# Server tool to manipulate video uploads

Tags: image, video, webserver

Looking for a tool to install on a webserver that can handle image/video conversion to flv. I am using php so the tools should have API's to allow scripting. I know of ffmpeg but is there any others or is this my only alternative.

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG is really your only viable option.  It supports the most formats, and works efficiently.